# C# Opengl Convert single value to RGB <0,1>

Tags: c#, opengl, colors

I need to convert single value to RGB in C# to color a single point. This values are stored on list, one value to one point.

1) I know the min and the max value from list.

2) The ranges of value could be any, eg: -13, 20000, 0.000234 ...

3) Red, Green and Blue value MUST BE in range <0;1>. Iam using glColor3f.

How to conver it ?

Comment: `(val - min) / (max - min)` where `min` and `max` are the smallest and largest possible values.

Comment: But I need THREE values, R, G and B. If I use Your formula to calculate EACH, it makes no sense.

Comment: You only have one value though. Just set it the converted value to R and leave G and B as zero (or, better yet, use a texture format that only has an R channel).

Comment: This makes no sense, beacouse I cant get full range of colors.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're trying to encode a value in a texture so you can retrieve it in a shader, then doing that is fine. If you're just trying to color some object based on a value, there's many ways to do that.

Comment: Iam trying to color point. Each point have ONE value (eg temperature). Now, I need a full palete of colors to visualization look for reliable. Low values for blue, high for red for example. Using glColor3f(r,g,b). r, g, b must be in range <0,1>. If there are many ways, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no canonical way to map a single 1-dimensional value into the [3-dimensional space of colors](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/RGB_Cube_Show_lowgamma_cutout_b.png).  You are basically looking for an automatic way to generate a curve in 3d from a 1-dimensional interval.  Obviously there are infinitely many ways to do that.

Commenters suggest using using a fixed color chromaticity (such as red) and varying its brightness.  While this is perhaps the simplest approach, you apparently don't want to do that.

One alternative would be to map your value into the [HSV Color Space](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/HSV_color_solid_cylinder_alpha_lowgamma.png), mapping the real value into the [hue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and choosing some fixed values for the saturation and value (start with the maximum values and tone them down if the result is too bright.)

Thus the algorithm might look like:

1. Get the max and min.
2. Map the min to a minimum angle for hue, say 10 degrees, and map the max to a maximum angle, say 350 degrees.  (You will need to play with these boundaries).
3. For each value in the list,
4. Interpolate the value between the max and min hues:

   ```
   var hue = minHue + (maxHue - minHue) * (value - min)/(max - min)
   ```
5. Given you fixed values for saturation and value (say 1.0 to start for each), map them to the RGB color space using code from this answer: [Is there a built-in C#/.NET System API for HSV to RGB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335426/is-there-a-built-in-c-net-system-api-for-hsv-to-rgb).
6. The above returns R, G and B in the range of 0-255.  Normalize them to be between 0 and 1 as per your requirements.

If you are familiar with [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html), its color picker tool allows you to pick hues (H) for given values of S and V:

[image]

You would be doing basically the same thing as picking a color from the tool.