# C# Recolored Image Pixelated

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, imageprocessor

I'm attempting to load an image from the filesystem, re-color it, then save it to a Stream. The images in question are fairly simple, single-color, geometric shapes.

I have it working, but the resulting images are heavily pixelated along the edges.

I've tried System.Drawing:

```
var colorMap = new ColorMap
{
    OldColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255),
    NewColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)
};
var imageAttrs = new ImageAttributes();
imageAttrs.SetRemapTable(new[] {colorMap});

var newImage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);

graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

graphics.DrawImage(image,
    new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
    0, 0,
    image.Width,
    image.Height,
    GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
    imageAttrs);
```

I've also tried the ImageProcessor library, using its ReplaceColor() method, but I get the same results (although not quite as bad).

Any way to do this and preserve the nice smooth edges my original image had?

Comment: Have your tried Bit Miracle LibTiff.Net for this

Comment: I pretty sure I have nailed your __problem__ but for the best __solution__ you should tell us more: How are those images created? How large and how many are there? How many variation will you need and what is the overall goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The images in question are fairly simple, single-color, geometric
>   shapes.

Sounds fine but the problem is that your 'Table' of colors is far too short unless the images really and truely contain only the one color you put into the map! But those images most certainly have been drawn with anti-aliasing on and therefore all anti-aliased pixels are not covered by the Table. You need to

- **Either** use images without antialiasing, but they won't be as smooth as you want it
- **Or** build a proper `ColorMap`, see below
- **Or** write a function of your own, best using [Lockbits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976620/how-can-i-color-pixels-that-are-not-black-in-bitmap-in-yellow-using-lockbits/25977692?s=1|3.2638#25977692) for speed..
- **Or** you can try to achieve the color changes with a [`ColorMatrix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which combines speed and 'color smartness'. However not all changes lend itself to using it.. So you may want to tell us about the kind of changes you will need..

You are not alone:

I just tried the [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h9aaxdk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on msdn because it looks so wrong: Saving `Jpg` files should not work (as it will always generate its own color tables) and look and behold **it works, but only** because  the files created on my machine are `Png` files with the **wrong** extension! Once you add   `ImageFormat.Jpeg` to the save it stops working..:

Original MSDN code:

```
myBitmap.Save("Circle2.jpg");
```

Changed to

```
myBitmap.Save("Circle2.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Results:

[image] [image]

To build a proper `ColorMap` you will need to a) loop over all pixels and collect all distinct colors (simple but slow) and then calculate the target colors (fast but not necessarily simple or well-defined.)

Here are two routines that show how to build a complete `ColorMap`:

```
List<Color> GetDistinctColors(Bitmap bmp)
{
    List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x,y);
            if (!colors.Contains(c)) colors.Add(c);
        }

    return colors;
}

List<Color> ChangeColors(List<Color> colors)
{
    List<Color> newColors = new List<Color>();
    foreach(Color c in colors)
    {
        int A = 255;   //  here you need..
        int R = c.G;   //  ..to write..
        int G = c.R;   //  ..your custom .
        int B = c.B;   //  ..color change code!!
        newColors.Add(Color.FromArgb(A,R,G,B));
    }
    return newColors;
}
```

To use it you write:

```
// prepare the two lists:
List<Color> colors = GetDistinctColors((Bitmap)myImage);
List<Color> newColors = ChangeColors(colors);


// Create a complete color map
ColorMap[] myColorMap = new ColorMap[colors.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < colors.Count; i++)
{
   myColorMap[i] = new ColorMap();
   myColorMap[i].OldColor = colors[i];
   myColorMap[i].NewColor = newColors[i];
}
```

Note that writing the correct code for the ChangeColor function is anything but simple. Not only will you have to know what you want, you also need the right tools to achieve it. In my code example above I have done a very simplistic channel swap. This will usually not result in what you want: Neither the prime colors nor the anti-aliased pixels can be changed so simply. Instead you should transform from RGB to HSL or HSV and change the hue there! See here for a [SetHue example!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759764/c-sharp-sethue-or-alternatively-convert-hsl-to-rgb-and-set-rgb/28760071?s=2|0.1152#28760071)