# How to smooth exterior color gradient in Mandelbrot fractal generation?

Tags: fractals, mandelbrot

This is my progress with a mandelbrot fractal generation:

[image]

It appears with cases where the edge cases between colors are small, it has a good "blending" effect. However, as the distance between colors become larger, you can see very explicitly and evidently the separation of colors. I was wondering, how would I achieve a blending effect without using something like bicubic interpolation post-processing?

Attached is the code I have to generate the fractal:

```
public static void drawFractal()
{
    Complex Z;
    Complex C;

    double x;
    double y;

    // The min and max values should be between -2 and +2
    double minX = -2.0; // use -2 for the full-range fractal image
    double minY = -2.0; // use -2 for the full-range fractal image
    double maxX = 2.0; // use 2 for the full-range fractal image
    double maxY = 2.0; // use 2 for the full-range fractal image

    double xStepSize = ( maxX - minX ) / width;
    double yStepSize = ( maxY - minY ) / height;
    int maxIterations = 100;
    int maxColors = 0xFF0000;

    // for each pixel on the screen
    for( x = minX; x < maxX; x = x + xStepSize)
    {
        for ( y = minY; y < maxY; y = y + yStepSize )
        {
            C = new Complex( x, y );
            Z = new Complex( 0, 0 );
            int iter = getIterValue( Z, C, 0, maxIterations );

            int myX = (int) ( ( x - minX ) / xStepSize );
            int myY = (int) ( ( y - minY ) / yStepSize );
            if ( iter < maxIterations )
            {
                myPixel[ myY * width + myX ] = iter * ( maxColors / maxIterations ) / 50; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That *is* each step in the fractal.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the number of steps? I don't think I am asking the right questions at the moment..

Comment: It seems like [Exterior DEM/M](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/demm) might be relevant.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369438/smooth-spectrum-for-mandelbrot-set-rendering?rq=1

Comment: Hmm. The problem I have with that smooth coloring algorithm is that it works on a double. When I set my pixel to the `myPixel` array, that value is a bit-fiddled RGB.