# What would be the best choice of smooth coloring algorithm for Mandelbrot

Tags: java, colors, smoothing, fractals, mandelbrot

I am rendering a mandelbrot set and have already achieved somewhat smooth coloring, but when looking closer the picture becomes very noisy. I am wondering, what would be the best way to improve my coloring to achieve better aesthetics. Would using histogram coloring help remove the rough pixelated areas?
[Here is a render of the fractal using 10 000 iterations.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVisR.jpg)

This is the way I'm generating and assigning colors right now:

```
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            int black = 0;
            int[] colors = new int[max]; //max is the maximum number of iterations
            for (int i = 0; i<max; i++) {
                colors[i] = Color.HSBtoRGB(i/256f, 1, i/(i+8f));
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < colors.length / 2; i++)
            {
                int temp = colors[i];
                colors[i] = colors[colors.length - i - 1];
                colors[colors.length - i - 1] = temp;
            }

           ...
           ...
           ...

                    if (iterations < max) image.setRGB(col, row, colors[iterations]);
                    else image.setRGB(col, row, black);
                }
            }

            //ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("mandelbrot_seeria90"+Integer.toString(i)+".png"));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("resotest.png"));
```

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1243788/216248

Comment: The question does not sound like it's asking for a smooth interpolation of the colors, but rather for a "general smoothing" of the image. This may be a bit fiddly (you can't just use some gaussian to blur the final image). But you might, for each pixel, take the a average of the surrounding pixels where the number of iterations was not exceeded (i.e. the average of all surrounding pixels that are "not black")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution that may produce acceptable results is simply to anti-alias using 2x2, 3x3 or 4x4 super sampling, and generate each pixel by averaging the color values (not the iteration count) of a block of 4, 9 or 16 pixels.

This approach is just a general image rendering technique, it's not using any specific knowledge of Mandelbrot fractals to the problem, but you could optimize it by calculating the iteration count for neighbouring whole pixels and only doing the sub-sampling step if the counts are not all the same. This means that you'll only be doing it where it counts: at the boundary between 2 iteration counts or in noisy areas with lots of different counts next to each other.

You can test this by generating a test image and then shrinking it down by a scale factor in an image editing application (make sure you have filtering turned on). If it looks ok then you can implement it by adding an extra couple of for loops inside your existing inner pixel loop, for each sub-pixel, incrementing *c* by 1/2, 1/3 or 1/4 of the pixel step. Add up the color values and divide by the appropriate amount.

Answer (score 0):

Think cyclic, were the end value reaches the start value in a cycle, and you have several cycles.

Test it by creating a horizontal gamma, like `|||| ... |||` of the colors.

Something like:

```
fill:
for (int i = 0; i < max; ) {
    for (int h = 0; h < NH; ++h) {
        float hValue = ((float)h) / NH;
        for (int b = 0; b < NB; ++b) {
            doublebValue = ((double)b) / NB; // 0 .. 1
            bValue = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI  * bValue); // -1 .. 1
            bValue = (2 + bValue) / 3; // 0.33 .. 1
            colors[i] = Color.HSBtoRGB(hValue, 1, (float) bValue);
            ++i;
            if (i >= max) {
                break fill;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather too much for a comment, but not a definitive answer, sorry.

You can easily make a smooth colour graduation where the contours are widely spread, but in the neighbourhood of the M-Set ("infinite" iterations) the image becomes apparently chaotic, with adjacent pixels having very different numbers of iterations, so it appears noisy. When a zoom is created this is even more apparent and the noisy area appears to "dance".

I found the best solution was to use a gray scale in these areas, based on the difference in iterations of 8 neighbouring pixels. Assuming the "infinite" area is coloured black, such grey pixels would be blackest where there is most variation in the neighbours, or some neighbours are on the M-Set. On the shallower side, when there are some neighbours of the same depth, I would gain some colour tone from them. And in the middle ground where no neighbours have the same depth, the shade of grey would be based on their variation.

I used C and assembler (for the iteration).