# Can't get color smoothness to work with mandelbrot set using CImg

Tags: c++, mandelbrot, cimg

So in a step to learn C++ i decided to try to implement the mandelbrot set using CImg. Here is my program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

#define cimg_use_png
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;

const int MAX_ITER = 80;
const int WIDTH = 600;
const int HEIGHT = 400;
const int DEPTH = 1;
const int COLOR_SPECTRUM = 3;

const int RE_START = -2;
const int RE_END = 1;
const int IM_START = -1;
const int IM_END = 1;

double mandelbrot(const std::complex<double> &value) {
    std::complex<double> z(0, 0);
    int n = 0;
    while (abs(z) <= 2 && n < MAX_ITER){
        z = (z * z) + value;
        n += 1;
    }

    if(n == MAX_ITER) {
        return n;
    }

    return n + 1 - log(log2(norm(z)));
}

int main() {
    CImg<int> img(WIDTH, HEIGHT, DEPTH, COLOR_SPECTRUM, 0);
    img.RGBtoHSV();

    cimg_forXY(img, x, y) {
        std::complex<double> complex(RE_START + ((double)x / WIDTH) * (RE_END - RE_START),
                                     IM_START + ((double)y / HEIGHT) * (IM_END - IM_START));
        double m = mandelbrot(complex);

        int hue = (255 * m / MAX_ITER);
        int saturation = 255;
        int value = 0;
        if (m < MAX_ITER) {
            value = 255;
        }

        int color[] = { hue, saturation, value };
        img.draw_point(x, y, color);
    }

//    img.HSVtoRGB().display("Mandelbrot");
    img.HSVtoRGB().save_png("output/test.png");

    return 0;
}
```

I manage to draw out the classic mandelbrot shape, but then i tried implementing smoothing to get rid of the ugly banding. But i cant get it to really work.

And seriously tbh i have no idea what i'm doing because math is hard.

This is what i get
[image: Pink mandelbrot set]

I also get this warning when its saving the image

```
[CImg] *** Warning ***[instance(600,400,1,3,0x104800000,non-shared)] 
CImg<int>::save_png(): Instance has pixel values in 
[-1.65164e+07,65025], probable type overflow in file 'output/test.png'.
```

so apparently i have an overflow somewhere but i can't really tell where.

If anyone could help me and explain what I'm doing, and point out all the wrong things i have done but in a simple way, i would be forever grateful.

**UPDATE**

so by adding a normalization step i managed to get a better image:

```
img.HSVtoRGB()
    .normalize(0, 255)
    .save_png("output/test.png");
```

And the overflow error is gone.

[image: Mandelbrot gradient]

But there seems to be something wrong in the conversion between HSV and RGB.

Everything that is white should be black.

The HSV values i'm writing are  255, 255, 0

but it gets converted to 255, 255, 255 in RGB which is wrong. It should get converted to black.

**UPDATE 2**

As Bob informed me Hue and Saturation is not a number between 0..100 it's represented by a number between 0..1.

That was my main misstake and why i got an overflow and the blacks became white. By correcting that and doing the small fixes Bob suggested i now get:

[image: Correct Mandelbrot]

Comment: Debug what sort of values you're stuffing into `color`.

Comment: OT: Please note that you could use [std::log2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2) and [std::norm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/norm).

Comment: the smothing is `n + 1 - log(log(abs(z))/log(2))/log(2)` part but i always just get this banding, that i showed in the image, and i don't know why.

Comment: @Bob oh yeah, thanks didn't know of the `log2`

Comment: Are you trying to get something like this http://www.fractalforums.com/mandelbrot-and-julia-set/coloring-points-inside-the-mandelbrot-set/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369438/smooth-spectrum-for-mandelbrot-set-rendering ?

Comment: @Tadman i have debug and i get all positive values between 0-255. I think it has to do something with the color depth and/or the conversion between HSV and RGB color space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HSV color model, the *hue* is usually expressed as an angle in degrees [0°, 360°), while the *saturation* and *value* are in the range [0, 1].

A way to fix the posted code is to adjust the values and their type stored in `img`.

```
CImg<double> img(WIDTH, HEIGHT, DEPTH, COLOR_SPECTRUM, 0);
//   ^^^^^^ I guess a float could be enough
// img.RGBtoHSV();  Here, is useless. CImg has no notion of the color space

cimg_forXY(img, x, y)
{
    std::complex<double> c(/* Get real and imaginary part from x and y */);

    double m = mandelbrot(c);

    double color[] = {
//  ^^^^^^    
        360.0 * m / MAX_ITER,       // hue
        1.0,                        // saturation
        (m < MAX_ITER) ? 1.0 : 0.0  // value
    };

    img.draw_point(x, y, color);
}

img.HSVtoRGB().normalize(0, 255).save_png("output/test.png");
```

Also note that in `mandelbrot()` you could use

```
while (std::norm(z) <= 4 && n < MAX_ITER) // 
{   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ To avoid a sqrt at every iteration

    // See e.g. https://linas.org/art-gallery/escape/smooth.html for this:
    return n + 1 - std::log2( std::log( std::norm(z) ) * 0.5 );       
}
```

Comment: that was it! i knew that hue was a value between 0 and 360 but i didn't know that saturation and value was a value between 0..1! i thought it was 0..100! I learnt something new today! you tha man @Bob__